# ipconfig on windows 7 outside of system32

Tags: windows-7, command-prompt, ipconfig, system32

I'm working on making an incident response disk and I wanted to be able to run a copy of ipconfig off of external media such as a usb drive.
This seems to work on my windows xp machine but when I copy ipconfig outside of system32 directory, it will not run.

I also noticed this issue with netstat and several other networking utilities.

What can I do to run a windows 7 version of ipconfig on an external drive?

Comment: Isn't ipconfig part of every windows install, so you wouldn't need to have it running on a USB stick?

Comment: It is part of every install but the idea is that I could be getting this information off of a system that is infected with malware, so the application and it's dll files could be compromised on the system so I want to use a trusted source on my usb drive.

Comment: you're better of running third party tools for your usb stick. `ipconfig.exe` for examples requires `sechost.dll`, `dnsapi.dll`, `winnsi.dll`, etc. they could all be infected. (try Nirsoft for some very handy tools)

Comment: Good tip moontear, but I am curious as to what ipconfig needs to run that makes it not work outside of the system32 folder.
I have even tried copying the entire system32 folder and running ipconfig within there and having it not work. I'm wondering what it is tied to now in windows 7 which prevents this from working.

Answer (score 3):

Several Windows networking utilities need a `.MUI` supporting file from the US-EN sub-folder in order to run. For example, `c:\windows\system32\ipconfig.exe` requires `c:\windows\system32\en-US\ipconfig.exe.mui` to run.

An easy way to copy the executable you want and its supporting file is to use the copy command using the `/s` (include sub-folders) option:

```
xcopy /s c:\windows\system32\netstat* d:\irtookit
xcopy /s c:\windows\system32\ipconfig* d:\irtookit
xcopy /s c:\windows\system32\whoami* d:\irtookit
```

For example, this will copy both `ipconfig` and `\US-EN\ipconfig.exe.mui` to `d:\irtoolkit`.

Now, if you run `d:\irtoolkit\ipconfig` it will work.